# Check duplicate array php and combine duplicate entry

Tags: php, arrays

My array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC A
    [1] => ABC B
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => DEF
            [1] => ABC A
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => DEF
            [1] => ABC B
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => GHI
            [1] => ABC A
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => GHI
            [1] => ABC B
        )

)
```

My goal is to create an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC A
    [1] => ABC B
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => DEF
            [1] => ABC A
            [2] => ABC B
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => GHI
            [1] => ABC A
            [2] => ABC B
        )

)
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: @Ganesh: Not sure how that will help here.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202108/merge-duplicate-array-values-in-a-multidimensional-array-php

Comment: i can't understand the way you want it te be orderer and merged

Comment: "My goal is to create an array *like this*" - huh? you have to explain the rule. voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use plain ol' foreach on this one. Consider this example:

```
$values = array(
    'ABC A',
    'ABC B',
    array('DEF', 'ABC A'),
    array('DEF', 'ABC B'),
    array('GHI', 'ABC A'),
    array('GHI', 'ABC B'),
);

$new_values = array();
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $new_values[$value[0]][0] = $value[0];
        $new_values[$value[0]][] = $value[1];
    } else {
        $new_values[] = $value;
    }
}

$new_values = array_values($new_values); // reindex

print_r($new_values);
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC A
    [1] => ABC B
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => DEF
        [1] => ABC A
        [2] => ABC B
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => GHI
        [1] => ABC A
        [2] => ABC B
    )

)
```

Comment: ohh my god, do not forget to always give this people the happiness. really thankyou it's work

Comment: +1 for managing to understand the question!