# PHP multidimensional array - Counting the duplicate and mingle the duplicate with original

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$users = array(
              array(1,'name1'),
              array(1,'name1'),
              array(2,'name2'),
              array(3,'name3')
         );
```

Now after adding the following code, i can make the unique array.

```
array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $users)));
```

I can count the duplicates with the following code. But it is missing the name field. So, i need to do something to get the name along with the id and count of duplicate.

```
array_count_values(array_map(function($item) {
        return $item['id'];
    }, $users));
```

Do i need to loop the array get something like this? Or is there any other trick in php?

```
$new_users = array(
              array(1,'name1', 2), //two times + descending order 
              array(2,'name2', 1), 
              array(3,'name3', 1)
         );
```

Comment: Upvote for using the word "mingle". It feels like an 80' school dance.

Comment: Not exactly same, but a similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202108/merge-duplicate-array-values-in-a-multidimensional-array-php

Comment: Instead of showing a bunch of almost correct code, describe what you're actually trying to achieve. You want to merge all duplicates into one item and count the number of duplicates?

Comment: @deceze I am updating the final result which i am expecting. It is all working good. Is there anyway to achieve them in shortest code to reduce the work load.

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_users = array_reduce($users, function (array $new_users, array $user) {
    $key = sha1(serialize($user));
    if (isset($new_users[$key])) {
        $new_users[$key][2]++;
    } else {
        $new_users[$key] = array_merge($user, [1]);
    }
    return $new_users;
}, []);
```

To deduplicate, use unique keys in an array. Here we use the hash of the serialised array as key, which is the simplest way to uniquely identify something more complex than a single value. Then simply increase a counter if the item already exists.